# Issue using Owner in Component Visibility filter

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning

I am trying to set component visibility for a lwc that I'm adding to a lighting page. However, when I try to search the owner field I can't find it as an option in the component visibility filters. I have looking through documentation to try to find anything about this limitation but I can't find anything. Is there a setting I need to change to allow me to use the owner field in the component visibility?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the Advanced tab of the Component Visibility filter

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use "$User.LastName" to reference the current user's details.  I'd suggest you use $User.Email, as this is more likely to be unique.. you can have two users with the same last name :)